# How to add a sound to your program?

Tags: java

I am trying to add sound in program. I have no experience how to add sound in program.
I am trying this but this code giving me exception "null". I don't know what argument I have to pass in playSound function. So help me please.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import sun.audio.*; //import the sun.audio package
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class Main {

    public Main() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello there");
        playSound("Hi there");

    }

    public static synchronized void playSound(final String url) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() { // the wrapper thread is unnecessary, unless
                                    // it blocks on the Clip finishing, see
                                    // comments
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                            AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem
                                    .getAudioInputStream(Main.class
                                            .getResourceAsStream("pacman_chomp.wav"
                                                    + url));
                            clip.open(inputStream);
                            clip.start();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to give the path to a .wav file or some other sound file.

Comment: @ console...
1st it print "Hello there" in second line "null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said your playSound method didn't work, here's a sound class I coded.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class AePlayWave extends Thread {

    protected static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    protected InputStream inputStream;

    public AePlayWave(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        if (DEBUG) System.out.println("AePlayWave constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (DEBUG) System.out.println("AePlayWave running");

        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = verifyInputStream();
        if (audioInputStream == null) {
            return;
        }

        AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        SourceDataLine audioLine = openInputStream(format);

        if (DEBUG) System.out.println(audioLine.getLineInfo());

        if (audioLine != null) {
            audioLine.start();
            playInputStream(audioInputStream, audioLine);
        }
    }

    protected AudioInputStream verifyInputStream() {
        if (DEBUG) System.out.println("AePlayWave verifyInputStream");
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
        try {
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inputStream);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return audioInputStream;
    }

    protected SourceDataLine openInputStream(AudioFormat format) {
        if (DEBUG) System.out.println("AePlayWave openInputStream");
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
        SourceDataLine audioLine = null;
        if (DEBUG) System.out.println("AePlayWave openInputStream try");
        try {
            audioLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            if (DEBUG) System.out.println("AePlayWave openInputStream getLine");
            audioLine.open(format);
            if (DEBUG) System.out.println("AePlayWave openInputStream open");
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return audioLine;
    }

    protected void playInputStream(AudioInputStream audioInputStream,
            SourceDataLine audioLine) {
        if (DEBUG) System.out.println("AePlayWave playInputStream");
        int externalBufferSize = (int) audioInputStream.getFrameLength() * 4;
        if (DEBUG) System.out.println("AePlayWave playInputStream externalBufferSize: " 
                + externalBufferSize);
        int nBytesRead = 0;
        byte[] abData = new byte[externalBufferSize];

        try {
            while (nBytesRead != -1) {
                nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
                if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
                    if (DEBUG) System.out.println("Bytes read: " + nBytesRead);
                    audioLine.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } finally {
            audioLine.drain();
            audioLine.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how it's called:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("alarm-clock-1.wav");
AePlayWave playWave = new AePlayWave(inputStream);
playWave.run();
```

Comment: I am getting error in this line 
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("alarm-clock-1.wav");
Error = "Cannot make a static reference to a non-static method getClass() from the type Object".
And thanks for Answering

Answer (score 1):

It might be giving you a null exception because it can't find the file. At the moment it is looking for a file called:

> "pacman_chomp.wavHi there"

Because the value of url is being set to "Hi there" and you are constructing it like this:

```
AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem
                                    .getAudioInputStream(Main.class
                                            .getResourceAsStream("pacman_chomp.wav"
                                                    + url));
```

I presume you want the file ""pacman_chomp.wav"? In which case remove the "+ url".

Comment: Well Chris thanks for answering.
you are right the file name is pacman_chomp.wave but it's strill not working :(

Comment: Is it in the right place? It will be looking for the file in the same location as your "Main.class" file

Answer (score 0):

Clip dont allow long audio files. See these classes which are from my game engine.

[`SoundState`](https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-java/source/browse/src/com/gej/sound/SoundState.java)
[`WavPlayer`](https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-java/source/browse/src/com/gej/sound/WavPlayer.java)
[`WavSound`](https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-java/source/browse/src/com/gej/sound/WavSound.java)

Then use this code.

```
// First load the sound
WavSound snd = WavPlayer.loadSound("pacman_chomp.wav");
// play it then
snd.play();
```

You may use these classes for free. Hope they helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
playSound("pacman_chomp.wav");


public static synchronized void playSound(final String url) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() { // the wrapper thread is unnecessary, unless
                                // it blocks on the Clip finishing, see
                                // comments
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem
                                .getAudioInputStream(Main.class
                                        .getResourceAsStream(url));
                        clip.open(inputStream);
                        clip.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }).start();
}
```

a: as stated above it looks for "pacman_chomp.wavHi there"

b: hardcoding is not recommended here. you lose the ability to reuse the code. as an example, you can't do this if you hardcode in the playSound method:

```
    playSound("pacman_chomp.wav");
    playSound("pacman_dies.wav");
```

in addition, the method name "playSound" becomes poorly named (in hardcoded file), because it will always play the pacman_chomp file (if pointed correctly).

c: what's the purpose of "Hi there" anyways?

Comment: I am just testing how to add Sound in program. i don't know what's this url argument do so i just send "Hi there" string.
If i succeed then i will add sound in my main program. Hope so u got me...Sorry for bad English .

Comment: the url is the path to the file. so if the file is in the same directory as the class, you can type "pacman_chop.wav" as the argument.

Comment: I did this but this thing also not working...

Comment: three things:
one: did you replace.getResourceAsStream("pacman_chomp.wav"
                                                    + url)); with 
 .getResourceAsStream(url));?
two:are the files in the same path? if not, you need to provide a path to the file.
three: did you spell the filename correctly?

if it doesn't work after this:
put a breakpoint here: clip.open(inputStream); if inputStream is null or it doesnt hit this breakpoint: then there is something wrong with: getAudioInputStream or getResourceAsStream